# Visual Studio 15.7.6 Update Issue: Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.

Tags: visual-studio, github, bitbucket, visual-studio-extensions

After updating Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.7.6, I'll get this error message while doing sync or fetch:

> Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   HttpRequestException encountered.    An error occurred while sending
>   the request. cannot spawn /C/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team
>   Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or
>   directory could not read Password for 'https://ershadi@bitbucket.org':
>   terminal prompts disabled

The issue is a bug, but is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried @Leo Liu-MSFT answer but it did not work for me , the only way it worked was to add password into bit-bucket URL

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Visual Studio 15.7.6 Update Issue: Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.

Yes, this is a known issue on Github: [Can't login to GitHub](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949).

You can try the workaround from KevinRamharak and whoisj:

KevinRamharak:

> Downloading the latest release and putting it on top of the files in
>   VIsual Studio 2017.
>
> ```
> 1. download the zip file gcmw-v1.17.0.zip from https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases
> 2. navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\ (or wherever your 'missing' git-askpass.exe resides).
>
> 3. make a copy of the git-core folder and rename it backup or something like that
> 4. put the files from the zip file on top of the contents of your new git-core folder and overwrite where prompted
> ```

whoisj:

> I'd like to announce GCM v1.17.1 Preview 1 is available for download.
>   While this won't directly fix the issue with Visual Studio being able
>   to authentication successfully with BitBucket, it should unblock you
>   if you...
>
> Download and install the tool Use Git for Windows to interact with
>   your BitBucket repository in a way that forces it to authenticate
>   Logon using the Atlassian provided BitBucket interface. Once you've
>   done this, your credentials will be cached in the Windows Credential
>   Manager, and Visual Studio should have access to them. Please, let me
>   know how this goes and best of luck.
>
> PS. Yes, we're still working towards a more permanent solution but I
>   wanted to provide a possible work around as early as possible.

Hope this helps.